# Automatically open the lightbox popup upon opening the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the JS i have:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var OSX = {
    container: null,
    init: function () {
        $("input.osx, a.osx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $("#osx-modal-content").modal({
                overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                containerId: 'osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                onClose: OSX.close
            });
        });
    },
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $("#osx-modal-content", self.container).show();
            var title = $("#osx-modal-title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).height()
                        + title.height()
                        + 20; // padding
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        200,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).show();
                        }
                    );
                }, 300);
            });
        })
    },
    close: function (d) {
        var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
        d.container.animate(
            {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
            500,
            function () {
                self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            }
        );
    }
};
OSX.init();

});
```

I'm using this lightbox script for survey and the html includes form,

and this code make the lightbox open by clicking on button, all i need is to use the same lightbox and make it automatically open upon opening the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your button exist on the page, because the quickest way would just be to run a jquery.click action on that button. Then you are not maintaining code twice that does the same thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just trigger `click()` programatically on a button that shows the popup after page loads.

Example:

```
$(function () {
  $('your_button').click();
})
```